# Error executing Seam EJBQL - "java.lang.IllegalStateException: invalid select clause for query"

Tags: java, hibernate, seam, ejbql

I'm trying to run a ejbql in my application but it's failing with the following error:
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: invalid select clause for query.

This is the query:

```
public void pesquisar()
{
    StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();

    query.append("SELECT OBJECT(licenca) FROM TblLicencas licenca");
    query.append(" WHERE upper(licenca.tblLivros.titulo) like '%" + termoPesquisa.toUpperCase() + "%'");
    tblLicencasList.setEjbql(query.toString());

    tblLicencasList.refresh();
}
```

In console, the output query generated by hibernate is this:

```
select
    top 26 tbllicenca0_.id_licenca as id1_8_,
    tbllicenca0_.data_geracao as data2_8_,
    tbllicenca0_.id_livraria as id3_8_,
    tbllicenca0_.id_livro as id4_8_,
    tbllicenca0_.id_status_licenca as id5_8_,
    tbllicenca0_.id_tipo_licenca as id6_8_ 
from
    DigitalDocumentsServerTeste.dbo.tbl_licencas tbllicenca0_,
    DigitalDocumentsServerTeste.dbo.tbl_livros tbllivros1_ 
where
    tbllicenca0_.id_livro=tbllivros1_.id_livro 
    and (
        upper(tbllivros1_.titulo) like '%ADV%'
    )
```

In my application i have several other queries similar to this that work perfectly.
When i mannualy execute this query in the database, it works well.
I'm using SQL Server 2005.

Thanks